# XCode pthread kext compilation (linking) issue

Tags: xcode, multithreading, macos, pthreads, clang

First of all, the code-in-question is available here:
https://github.com/i3roly/CMI8788

A brief description of my problem is that, while Xcode can compile the code into a Kext, the resulting kext is missing the pthread and OSSpinLock function calls.

Specifically, when I ran kextlibs -v 6 PCIAudioDriver.kext, I got this:

```
GagansMacPro:CMI8788 Gagan$ sudo kextlibs -v 6 PCIAudioDriver.kext/
Kext user-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext kernel-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext library architecture set to x86_64.
Kext library architecture is x86_64 (unchanged).
For all architectures:
    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily = 203.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily = 2.9
    com.apple.kpi.iokit = 14.5
    com.apple.kpi.libkern = 14.5

For x86_64:
    7 symbols not found in any library kext.
```

so I ran kextutil -v 6 on this kext and I got this:

```
Loading PCIAudioDriver.kext.
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received kext load request from user space.
(kernel) Received request from user space to load kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver.
(kernel) Loading kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.bsd is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.libkern is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.mach is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily sending 3 personalities to the IOCatalogue and starting matching.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.iokit is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kec.pthread is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.unsupported is already loaded.
(kernel) Allocated link buffer for kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver at 0xffffff7f89b88000 (98304 bytes).
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]:   _OSSpinLockLock
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]:   _pthread_cond_init
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]:   _pthread_cond_timedwait
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]:   _pthread_mutex_init
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]:   _pthread_mutex_lock
(kernel) kxld[com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver]:   _pthread_mutex_unlock
(kernel) Can't load kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver - link failed.
(kernel) Failed to load executable for kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver.
(kernel) Kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver failed to load (0xdc008016).
(kernel) Failed to load kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver (error 0xdc008016).
(kernel) Kext com.CMedia.CMI8788.PCIAudioDriver removing all personalities naming it from the IOCatalogue.
Kernel error handling kext request - (libkern/kext) link error.
Failed to load PCIAudioDriver.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Failed to load PCIAudioDriver.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Check library declarations for your kext with kextlibs(8).
```

I have tried my best to tweak OSBundleLibraries, which are currently:

```
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily</key>
        <string>203.3</string>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily</key>
        <string>2.9</string>
        <key>com.apple.kec.pthread</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.bsd</key>
        <string>12.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>14.5</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>11.2</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>11.2</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.unsupported</key>
        <string>11.2</string>
    </dict>
```

but nothing is working. I am running XCode 7.2.1 (*with* the 10.10 **and** 10.11 SDKs) on 10.10.5.

are pthreads and osspinlock function calls hidden in com.apple.kpi.private or something? I really need these functions for my driver and I cannot do without them.

I do recall when I first tried to declare OSSpinLock the Xcode IDE would say "DID YOU MEAN IOSimpleLOCK?" (obviously not), which I fixed by changing

```
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>
```

to

```
#include </usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h>
```

but all this did was allow XCode to compile the code "successfully", which is obviously not the case if kextutil/libs are reporting missing symbols.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Siguza](http://newosxbook.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=417) from newosxbook forums, I can look past this problem.

The transcript of our exchange is [here](http://newosxbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=19485#).

[It turns out, and as Siguza patiently and painstakingly (arguably lovingly ;)) explained](http://newosxbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=19485#p23344), I had not wrapped my head around the transition from "kernel-land program" to "kernel-land driver" where the latter imposes additional constraints that forbid dependence on shared libraries (such as pthreads).

As such, I had to wrap the pthread_mutex_lock calls to IOLock, and temporarily use Siguza's [OSSpinLockLock macro that exploits the availability of OSSpinLockTry](http://newosxbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&p=23340#p23340)